# MS SQL GETDATE() not working in SQL command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, getdate

I am trying to update a record in my MS SQL database but cannot seem to get the `GETDATE()` function to work.

Will somebody look at the code below and tell me were am going wrong?

```
BEGIN
    update Bookings
  set TotalBookings = TotalBookings+1
  set LastBooked = GETDATE()
  where PropertyId='1007' 
END
```

Comment: You need to look at how to write [SQL: UPDATE Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php) properly!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong it should be:

```
BEGIN
  update Bookings
  set TotalBookings = TotalBookings+1 ,
      LastBooked = GETDATE()
  where PropertyId='1007' 
END
```

You are using `set` multiple times, instead use `set` once and separate your columns with comma.

For more info see: [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)